# Is java:comp/UserTransaction default in jboss 7.1.1

Tags: hibernate, jboss

I am migrating one of our solutions from Jboss 4.0.5 to Jboss 7.1.1, I have a sessionfactory name defined in my persistence.xml, but it kept on giving me org.hibernate.service.jndi.JndiException: Unable to lookup JNDI name [java:comp/UserTransaction] whenever my hibernateUtil want to make connection to the database.. Please, what could be the issue?

I did not set a lookup for java:comp/UserTransaction anywhere in my code, but I am getting this error: org.hibernate.service.jndi.JndiException: Unable to lookup JNDI name [java:comp/UserTransaction]. Please I need help....

Answer (score 1):

My code was using the default before, what i did was to add the code below to my hibernateUtil and the issue got resolved.
    UserTransaction tx = null;
        InitialContext ctx2 = new InitialContext();
        tx = (UserTransaction) ctx2.lookup("java:jboss/UserTransaction");

Comment: I was facing the similar problem and answer from the above by using JNDI name as  "java:jboss/UserTransaction"  resolved my problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `java:jboss/UserTransaction`, `java:comp/UserTransaction` is only available to **EE component code**.